How can I debug JavaScriptBundler compile errors in Flutter?
I'm currently working an flutter project that builds and runs without any issues when building for Android or iOS. Now I'd like to start working on the web version of the project, but I keep getting errors about methods not being found (in libraries) which prevents the build from completing.
I've created a whole new flutter project, that builds fine, and then I've pasted the content of my pubspec.yaml's dependencies in the new project's pubspec file and I can reproduce the exact same errors.
The problem is I don't understand how I can debug this any futher, nor where I have to look to resolve any dependency issues, because flutter pub get doesn't give me any issues.
The errors are in the lines of:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_app_check_web-0.1.0+19/lib/src/interop/app_check_interop.dart:21:10: Error: Type 'PromiseJsImpl' not found.

The pubspec.yaml file looks like this:
name: best_practice_flutter
description: "A new Flutter project."

# Prevent accidental publishing to pub.dev.
publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.57+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.4.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: 4.15.8
  firebase_auth: 4.14.1
  firebase_core: 2.27.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: 5.4.5
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.2
  flutter_dotenv: 5.1.0
  get: 4.6.6
  google_sign_in: 6.1.6
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
  flutter_native_splash: 2.3.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.13.1
  flutter_svg: 2.0.7
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: 23.2.6
  flutter_tabler_icons: 1.2.0
  package_info_plus: 4.1.0
  qr_flutter: 4.1.0
  dio: 5.3.3
  flutter_easyloading: 3.0.5
  url_launcher: 6.1.14
  flutter_timezone: 1.0.7
  mobile_scanner: ^5.1.1
  device_info_plus: 9.0.3
  jiffy: 6.2.1
  appinio_swiper: 2.0.3
  sentry_flutter: 7.13.0
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: 0.14.2
  glassfy_flutter: 1.6.1
  intl: 0.18.1
  upgrader: 8.4.0
  stylish_bottom_bar: 1.0.3
  chat_bubbles: 1.5.0
  shared_preferences: 2.2.2
  jwt_decoder: 2.0.1
  aptabase_flutter: 0.1.1
  firebase_app_check: 0.2.1+8
  mixpanel_flutter: ^2.2.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^5.1.6
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  http: ^0.13.6

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true

  assets:
    # Add assets from the images directory to the application.
    - assets/images/


How can I debug the javascript compiler properly so I can figure out what is going on?
My run configuration is
    {
      "name": "project-app-web",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "args": [
        "-d",
        "chrome",
      ]
    }

Since the above error is firebase specific, I also tried updating firebase, but that didn't resolve the issue either. In addition, I've made sure that firebase is configured in the project, but that didn't resolve anything either.

You are using many fixed versions, for example: firebase_app_check: 0.2.1+8 Unless you need specific versions, prefer prefixing versions with ^.  Use flutter pub deps to see why you are ending up with 0.1.0+19 instead of 0.2.something. As an aside, it's conventional to list dependencies in alphabetical order so that they are easier to read.
